# Unity(c#) - Как заспавнить объект , чтоб он летел и уничтожал другой?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, transform

У меня возникла проблема. В моей игре есть объект (Ракета) которая падает вниз. Когда игрок подобрал эту *Ракету* она должна вылетать с того положения где находится игрок и уничтожать другой объект (Бомба).
К сожалению у меня выбивает ошибку.
***** - Это Код Полёта *****
`{

```
[SerializeField]
private float fallSpeed = 3f; // Скорость падения объекта

void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.y < -6f){
        Destroy(gameObject); }

    transform.position -= new Vector3(0, fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

}`
*****- Когда происходит действие- *****

```
 if (other.tag == "Rocket")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        StartCoroutine(RocketShot());
        StopCoroutine(RocketShot());
    }
}

private IEnumerator RocketShot()
{
    rocket = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    rocket = false;
}
```

****- Мой Код Спавна - *****

```
private float _shotSpeed = 5f;
private Transform _player;
private Transform _bombPoint;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject _rocketObject;
private float _spawnTime = 3f;

void Start()
{
    _player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    _bombPoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Bomb").GetComponent<Transform>();
    InvokeRepeating("Update", 0, _spawnTime);
}

void Update()
{
    if (Player.rocket)
    {
        GameObject RocketPrefab = Instantiate( _rocketObject, _player.position, Quaternion.identity);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(_player.position, _bombPoint.position, _shotSpeed);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] [Tooltip("Require component \"Roket\"")] private GameObject _roketPrefub;
    SerializeField] _attackSpeed = 3f;
    private bool _attacking;
    Private float _attackTimer;

    private void OnValidate () {
        if (_roketPrefub != null && _roketPrefub.GetComponent<Roket>() == null) {
            _roketPrefub = null;
            Debug.LogError("\"Roket Prefub\" not contain \"Roket\" component");
        }
    }

    private void Start () {
        _attackTimer = _attackSpeed;
        _attacking = true;
    }

    private void Update () {
        _attackSpeed += Time.deltaTime;
        if (_attacking && _attackSpeed > _attackSpeed) {
            _attackSpeed = 0;
            LaunchRoket(Bomb.transform);
        }
    }

    private void LaunchRoket (Transform target) {
        if (_roketPrefub != null) {
            GameObject NewRoket = Instantiate(_roketPrefub);
            Roket Roket = NewRoket.GetComponent<Roket>();
            Roket.Lounch(transform, target);
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
public class Roket : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float _detonationRange = 0.5f;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Transform _target;
    private bool _lounched;

    public void Lounch (Transform player, Transform target) {
        _transform = transform;
        _target = target;
        _lounched = true;
        _transform.position = player.position
    }

    private void Detonation () {
        if (_target != null)
            _target.gameObject.AddComponent<Fall>();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void Update () {
        if (_lounched) {
            if (_target != null) {
                _transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(_transform.position, _target.position, _speed*Time.deltaTime);
                _transform.LookAt(_target.position);
                if (Vector3.Distance(_transform.position, _target.position) < _detonationRange)
                    Detonation();
            } else
                Detonation();
        }
    }
}
```

-

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent] // !!!
public class Fall : MonoBehaviour {
    private float _speed = -3f;
    private float _destroyY = -6f;
    private Transform _transform;

    private void Start () {
        _transform = transform;
    }

    void Update () {
        _transform.position += new Vector3(0, _speed, 0)*Time.deltaTime;
        if (_transform.position.y < _destroyY)
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```